# Даны две строки: S1 и S2. Удалить из строки S1 все подстроки, совпадающие с S2. Если таких подстрок нет, то вывести S1 без изменений

Tags: javascript

Даны две строки: S1 и S2. Удалить из строки S1 все подстроки, совпадающие с S2. Если таких подстрок нет, то вывести S1 без изменений. 
вот наработки помогите исправить

```
s1="qwer zxc   qwer qwzerz";
s2="qwer";
for( i = 0; i < s1.length;i++)
     if(s1.substr(i,s2.length) != s2)
    {
      s1.substr(i,s2.length);
    }else{
          console.log(s1)
   }
console.log(s1)
```

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью *string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)* + *RegExp*:

```
var s1="qwer zxc   qwer qwzerz";

s1 = s1.replace(/qwer/gi, "");
console.log(s1);
```

Если вам необходимо передавать строку по которой идет поиск в качестве переменной, то код будет выглядеть так:

```
var s1="qwer zxc   qwer qwzerz";
var s2= new RegExp("qwer", "gi");

s1 = s1.replace(s2, "");
console.log(s1);
```

**Определение ключей:**

g — глобальное сопоставление

i — игнорирование регистра при сопоставлении

Comment: О регулярных выражениях можно посмотреть [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 2):

Строго по делу хорошей практикой в вашей задаче может быть перобразование строки в массив и использование циклов что бы проверить каждое из значений внутри цикла. Если значение внутри цикла совпадает с значением s2 то добавим это значение в новый массив и по окончанию цикла соберем массив в строку используя join с и пробел между значений. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
var s1="qwer zxc   qwer qwzerz";
var s2="qwer";
var b=[];

for( var i = 0; i < s1.split(' ').length; i++)
    if(s1.split(' ')[i] !== s2){
        b.push(s1.split(' ')[i]);
    }
console.log(b.join(' '));
```

[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g2e8fxh/)

Так же хорошей практикой будет использование var перед присвоением значения к переменным.